# Whether we can rename a view in CCRC

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

Is there any command used for renaming a view in *ClearCase Remote Client*?

For example, I create a web view with name `fries_apple_wview`. Is there any way to change the name of `fries_apple_wview` to `fries_pie_wview` without affecting other settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, and there is no native renaming feature for views (either dnyamic or snapshot in CC7.x, or web view or dynamic view in ClearTeam 8.x)

The easiest way is to:

- create a second view,
- make sure everything works like in the first,
- and delete the first